# How to split the array of objects one by one in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to split the array of objects  one by one return objects in javascript,if it is possible or not.My given sample data is

```
var data=[{a:10,b:20},{c:10,d:30},{e:30,f:40}]
```

And finally split the data like given

```
{a:10,b:20}
{c:10,d:30}
{e:30,f:40}
```

Comment: Whats wrong with accessing data using index? like `data[0]`

Comment: Use array `Index` for accessing data. Why don't you show your effort?

Comment: do you mean to set the object as individual vars? the data is already how you want it, you can't just have object floating around

Comment: i wrote that data.split("\n")
error will be raising

Comment: *"split the array of objects one by one return objects"*. Try `data.shift()`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [**Foreach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
var data=[{a:10,b:20},{c:10,d:30},{e:30,f:40}]
data.forEach(function(element, index, array){
  console.log(element);//use as you want
});
```

Output:

```
Object { a=10, b=20}
Object { c=10, d=30}
Object { e=30, f=40}
```